# Manipulate EAP negotiation

Tags: network, man-in-the-middle, python, 802.1x, wpa2-eap

The EAP method to use is suggested from the client to the server during the EAP negotiation.

I'm trying to make the EAP negotiation ends on one specific EAP method (inner authentication included) of my choosing.

I was wondering if could be possible, using scapy, to sniff the packets related to the EAP negotiation and change the suggested EAP method.

Do you think that this could actually work?